# how to load a long panel dataset in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panel dataset in the long format, that is observations in the data are at the Panel_ID - Day level. I have, say, m Panel_IDs and each Panel_ID has T(m) Day observations.

For instance, the data would look like this. I show an example with 2 panel IDs (1 and 2) but the data contains a lot of them. X is one variable of interest.

```
Panel_ID Day X  
1  2-feb  5  
1  3-feb  4.3  
1  5-feb  3  
2  2-feb  0  
2  5-feb  0.5  
2  8-feb  3.2
```

etc. Days are not necessarily the same across Panel_IDs and each Panel_ID has its own number of daily observations.

How can I load this dataset in Pandas so that Pandas recognize its panel structure?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of how your data looks?

Comment: hi firelynx.. here you go. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load it normally, with `read_csv()` or whatever.  I copied your data and used `read_clipboard()` myself.

Then, set the index:

```
df = df.set_index(['Panel_ID','Day'])

                  X
Panel_ID Day       
1        2-feb  5.0
         3-feb  4.3
         5-feb  3.0
2        2-feb  0.0
         5-feb  0.5
         8-feb  3.2
```

If you want, you are done at this point, but if you want to convert from dataframe to panel, then it is easy after you have indexed the df:

```
pan = df.to_panel()
```

Honestly, I generally prefer to keep things as a multi-indexed dataframe rather than add the complexity of the panel structure, but you can do things either way.  Note, that even keeping it as a standard dataframe, you can do lots of reshaping easily with things like `stack()`.  For example, convert from narrow to wide with `unstack()`:

```
df.unstack(level=1)

             X                  
Day      2-feb 3-feb 5-feb 8-feb
Panel_ID                        
1            5   4.3   3.0   NaN
2            0   NaN   0.5   3.2
```

Also see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).